# haveing this error TypeError: ethers.JsonRpcProvider is not a function

Tags: blockchain

pls i need help on this TypeError: ethers.JsonRpcProvider is not a function

TypeError: ethers.JsonRpcProvider is not a function
at main (/Users/djlazer/blockchain-dev/ethers-simple-storage/deploy.js:12:27)
at Object. (/Users/djlazer/blockchain-dev/ethers-simple-storage/deploy.js:70:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
djlazer@DEEJAYs-MacBook-Pro ethers-simple-storage %

trying to create a contract